# Setting a camera based on modelPanel

Tags: python, maya, mel

First of all, I don't code yet.

My problem is that every time I open a scene in maya, the render cam panel is replaced with a persp view, thus making it a useless duplicate. I didn't find  any way to make maya remember the panel with the camera and the options that was set before (hiding curves, etc). 
What I'd like to do is to get the panel of the current active camera and change the camera of that panel.

I found this code here, and I think it could be used.

In my case the camera I would like to set to is called renderCAM, but the panel to get the panel from is probably persp.

Thank you!

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def getPanelFromCamera(cameraName):
    listPanel=[]
    for panelName in cmds.getPanel( type="modelPanel" ):
        if cmds.modelPanel( panelName,query=True, camera=True) == cameraName:
            listPanel.append( panelName )
    return listPanel

print getPanelFromCamera("persp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is different piece of code that could help you. Im not sure where you are stuck.

```
# get all default models
models = [i for i in cmds.lsUI(p=True) if 'modelPanel' in i]
# get first panel
myPane = cmds.paneLayout('viewPanes', q=True, pane1=True)
# get panel in focus but might not be your solution
panel = cmds.getPanel(withFocus=True)

#query camera
currentCam = cmds.modelPanel(myPane, q=True, cam=True)

# set camera
cmds.modelPanel(myPane, e=True, cam='renderCAM')
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't work as expected but probabl could help.